# iTunes Keyboard Shortcut for exiting search function

Tags: itunes

In iTunes on OS X, you can search for music in your library by using the `CMD+F` shortcut. However, as far as I can tell, there exists no shortcut for accessing those items once the search has completed. This isn't a huge problem, but it certainly would make searching faster if such a shortcut existed. Does anyone know if this exists? Thanks.

Edit: I should note that I use the "Songs" tab (as opposed to the Albums, Artists, Genres, etc. tabs).

Answer (score 1):

Once the results are returned to you, you can use the up and down arrows followed by the Return key in order to select the results. If you mean by exiting out of the search bar entirely, try pressing the Tab key.

Comment: Using the autofill search results would take me out of the "Songs" tab. Pressing the `Tab` key needs to be pressed many times in order to get to the search results.

Comment: What version of iTunes are you using? I can't seem to replicate your results on my end. I'm using iTunes 11.1.

Comment: I'm also using 11.1. I'm not really following what results you _are_ getting though. Can you elaborate?